# Enable / Disable many radioButtons having different ids

Tags: javascript, html, passwords, thymeleaf

What I have built so far is that I have a form with a few radioButtons and a password field.
Now, I want to activate the password field as soon as the corresponding radioButton is clicked.
That would work so far, if id for all password fields would not be the same.

This is my code so far:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/passwordaenderung}" th:object="${UserCreationDto}" method="post" onsubmit="return checkPassword()">
   <fieldset>
      <table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Username</th>
               <th>Password</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr th:each="user, itemStat : *{users}">
               <td><input type="radio" name="radiobutton" th:value="*users[__${itemStat.index}__].username}" id="raidoButtonCheck" onclick="document.getElementById('pwd').removeAttribute('disabled')" /></td>
               <td><input th:field="*users[__${itemStat.index}__].username}" disabled/></td>
               <td><input type="password" name="passwordField" th:field="*{users[__${itemStat.index}__].password}" id="pwd" disabled/></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <input type="submit" id="submitButton" th:value="Speichern">
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

So, does it look like in my browser:

[image]

And so does the interpreted / compiled code look like:

[image]

I hope someone can tell me please how do I get a different id for all password fields so that the correct one will be enabled via the

```
document.getElementById('pwd').removeAttribute('disabled')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically set the ids of each input using `th:id`. You can use the iterator index so that it can be unique. The following code should work.

```
<tr th:each="user, itemStat : *{users}">
    <td><input type="radio" name="radiobutton" th:value="*users[__${itemStat.index}__].username}" class="radioButton" th:onclick="${'document.getElementById('''+ itemStat.index +''').removeAttribute(''disabled'')'}" /></td>
    <td><input th:field="*users[__${itemStat.index}__].username}" disabled/></td>
    <td><input type="password" name="passwordField" th:field="*{users[__${itemStat.index}__].password}" th:id="${itemStat.index}" disabled/></td>
</tr>
```

If you want to disable all other inputs, when you click on one of them, then I would recommend adding a class to all inputs and changing your on click for function.

**JS**

```
<script>
    function inputClick(id) {
        var passwordFields = document.getElementsByClassName("passwordField");
        for(i = 0; i < passwordFields.length; i++) {
            passwordFields[i].disabled = true;
        }
        document.getElementById(id).removeAttribute('disabled');
    }
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<tr th:each="user, itemStat : *{users}">
    <td><input type="radio" name="radiobutton" th:value="*users[__${itemStat.index}__].username}" class="radioButton" th:onclick="${'inputClick('''+ itemStat.index +''')'}" /></td>
    <td><input th:field="*users[__${itemStat.index}__].username}" disabled/></td>
    <td><input class="passwordField" type="password" name="passwordField" th:field="*{users[__${itemStat.index}__].password}" th:id="${itemStat.index}" disabled/></td>
</tr>
```

The `js` can be added somewhere in the head or body or in a external `js` file.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked. I had to correct a typo at th:field, but that does not matter. Is it somehow possible to disable hide or disable all ot the others, too? Because, when enabling one and selecting another radioButton this radioButton will be enabled too.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Do you know what I could do to disable all the other fields or have only one active all the time? Because the user can enable one after the other at the moment.

Comment: Add a class to all inputs, and add a disable them when the button is clicked. You just need to get the elements by class in this case.

Comment: Maybe, you could help me with some code, please. I am not the best in HTML.

Comment: Sure, I am on my mobile now. Give me a few hours.

Comment: Sure, thank you very much. In the meantime, I am trying to find it out by myself. It should not seem as if I am doing nothing.

Comment: I just added the changes. Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Really great, thank you very much! I nearly did it the same way but I used the index on the class - do not know why, maybe it was too late - and that`s why it does not work. Now, that helps me a lot!!!! Thank you very much!